# Passing 4 images from activity to onther activity

Tags: android, android-layout

My App consists of 8 `Buttons` and 4 `ImageViews`. 4 buttons is "Browse" buttons, and 4 buttons is "Cancel" buttons.

What I have reached till now is when click browse we select an image from our gallery and display it in an `ImageViews`, and when we click cancel button it clear the `ImageView`.

So every 2 buttons which is "browse" button and "cancel" button is connected to one `ImageView`. and ... etc same as others buttons and `ImageViews`.

So what I need to implement is I need to pass the 4 images into next activity when user click to "NEXT" button, the 4 `ImageViews` transfer to another activity, but the next activity does't consists of `ImageViews` to display my passing images.

So I need to pass these images because I'm using put `extra` and `getExtra` for an `ImageViews.`

So what I need to implement exactly is: I need to pass images but if some `ImageView` doesn't have pictures. don't pass, but if `ImageViews` consists some pictures. pass these images it depends in the user "how many pic the user will add" but don't display passed images in next activity.

because I'm gonna put button called "Upload" where the user click that upload will upload images into DB as base64.

So how can u pass images and keep it hidden from the user like registration systems.??

**Attachment_Class**

```
public class Attachment_class extends AppCompatActivity  {

ImageView img_One;
Button btn_Browse_Image_One;
Button btn_Cancel_Image_One;

ImageView img_Two;
Button btn_Browse_Image_Two;
Button btn_Cancel_Image_Two;

ImageView img_Three;
Button btn_Browse_Image_Three;
Button btn_Cancel_Image_Three;

ImageView img_Four;
Button btn_Browse_Image_Four;
Button btn_Cancel_Image_Four;

Button Next;
Uri imageUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.attachment);

    img_One = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgView_One);
    btn_Browse_Image_One = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Broswe_image_one);
    btn_Cancel_Image_One = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Cancel_ImgView_One);

    img_Two = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgView_Two);
    btn_Browse_Image_Two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Broswe_image_two);
    btn_Cancel_Image_Two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Cancel_ImgView_Two);

    img_Three = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgView_Three);
    btn_Browse_Image_Three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Broswe_image_Three);
    btn_Cancel_Image_Three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Cancel_ImgView_Three);

    img_Four = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgView_Four);
    btn_Browse_Image_Four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Broswe_image_Four);
    btn_Cancel_Image_Four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Cancel_ImgView_Four);

    //btn_Browse_Image_One.setOnClickListener(this);
    // btn_Cancel_Image_One.setOnClickListener(this);
    // Next.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn_Browse_Image_One.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
        }
    });

    btn_Cancel_Image_One.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            img_One.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
    });

    btn_Browse_Image_Two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent x = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            x.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(x, 102);
        }
    });

    btn_Cancel_Image_Two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            img_Two.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
    });

    btn_Browse_Image_Three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent x = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            x.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(x, 103);

        }
    });

    btn_Cancel_Image_Three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            img_Three.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
    });

    btn_Browse_Image_Four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent x = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            x.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(x, 104);

        }
    });

    btn_Cancel_Image_Four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            img_Four.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
    });

    /*
    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Attachment_class.this, Upload_Class.class);
       //     Bitmap bitmap = img_One;  // take from img view
            ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bs); // it leads to error
            intent1.putExtra("byteArray", _bs.toByteArray());
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    */

    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(imageUri != null)
            {
                Intent x = new Intent(Attachment_class.this , Upload_Class.class);

            }
        }
    });


}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        imageUri = uri;
        Picasso.get().load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(img_One);
        // Add the recent dependency for Picasso
    }

    if(requestCode == 102 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        imageUri = uri;
        Picasso.get().load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(img_Two);
    }

    if(requestCode == 103 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        imageUri = uri;
        Picasso.get().load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(img_Three);
    }

    if(requestCode == 104 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        imageUri = uri;
        Picasso.get().load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(img_Four);
    }
}
}
```

**Upload.class**

```
public class Upload_Class extends Attachment_class {


Button bt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.the_openion);
    //btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Upload_Btn);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your image in a class that implements Parcelable so in your intent you use intent.putExtra("yourClass", yourClass);

and in the activity that receives the intent you use

Intent it = getIntent();
YourClass yourClass = it.getParcelableExtra("yourClass");